# AngularJS + D3 Animations Bar Chart Directive

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, css-transitions

I've got a AngularJS Directive carved from [this example](http://phloxblog.in/angulard3/start.html#.Usw6ANy9kk9).

I've read a few tutorials on doing transitions charts [like this one](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1429426) and also this [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364809/d3-js-transitions) but had no luck.

My chart is pretty basic and looks like: [image]

Below is my code for the directive, any ideas on why these transition examples aren't working?

```
       var width = 960 - opts.margin.left - opts.margin.right,
            height = 500 - opts.margin.top - opts.margin.bottom;

        var formatPercent = d3.format(opts.format);

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .tickFormat(formatPercent);

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(colorbrewer.Blues[4]);

        var svg = d3.select($elem[0]).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + opts.margin.left + opts.margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + opts.margin.top + opts.margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + opts.margin.left + "," + opts.margin.top + ")")

        $scope.render = function(data) {
            // remove all previous items before render
            svg.selectAll('*').remove();

            x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[opts.xaxisProperty]; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[opts.yaxisProperty]; })]);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("x", opts.xaxisPos)
                .attr("dx", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(opts.xaxisName);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", opts.yaxisPos)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(opts.yaxisName);

            var i = 0;
            svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(++i); })
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[opts.xaxisProperty]); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                 // tried to apply .transition() here
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[opts.yaxisProperty]); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[opts.yaxisProperty]); })      
        }
```

Comment: What transitions do you mean? You don't seem to have any transitions in your code.

Comment: Is this supposed to happen on a click event? If so which function is being called on click and what's happening exactly?

Comment: the bar charts sliding up upon render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the bars slide up on render, replace your current bar adding code with this:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("rect")
   .style("fill", function(d) { return color(++i); })
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[opts.xaxisProperty]); })
   .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
   .attr("y", height)
   .attr("height", 0)
   .transition().duration(500)
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[opts.yaxisProperty]); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[opts.yaxisProperty]); });
```