# How to make d3 area transition originate from bottom

Tags: d3.js

How can I make the transition of an area originate at the bottom of an svg rather than the top? When changing the height using this area function it will originate at the top.

```
area: function(width, height) {
    var x = this.xScale(width),
        y = this.yScale(height);

    return d3.svg.area()
           .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
           .y0(height)
           .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
}
```

Transition with new height **h**:

```
var area = this.area(w, h);

svg.datum(data)
           .transition()
           .ease('linear', 1, .3)
           .duration(1000)
           .attr('d', area);
```

I've found this SO question but can't translate it to my problem:

[D3.js Transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364809/d3-js-transitions)

**Update**

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/g3yS5/12/

The area a1 is situated at the top and when transitioning to a2 it pushes from top to bottom. I guess the solution to the problem involves getting the area to render to the bottom initially? If so how could I do this?

Comment: Are you saying that the problematic animation occurs when transitioning from no path to a rendered path, for the first time? Or is it during any arbitrary transition from one rendered path to another?

Comment: @meetamit The data remains the same between both states, I'm changing the area to a new height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/G3QER/) what you want?

```
svg.select('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 80)') // <---- here
    .transition()
    .ease('linear', 1, .3)
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)') // <---- then here
    .attr('d', a2);
```

It first translates the path to be at the bottom of the new height, then transitions that back to its natural position (NOTE: the translation is hard coded to be 80; you would want to compute it based on the height delta). This results in the path jumping to the new position, which might be what you expect.

Otherwise, you can also transition it in two steps. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/G3QER/1/).

Comment: I'd like the area to be at the bottom initially before the transition even so I'll just translate when I append the path. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Transitions start from whatever value the attribute you're animating currently is, so you can simply change that value before the transition starts:

```
svg.datum(data)
    .attr('d', startingArea) // set initial 'state'
  .transition().ease('linear', 1, .3).duration(1000)
    .attr('d', area);
```

In this case, `startingArea` could look a lot like your existing `area` function, but `y0` would be `0` perhaps, or maybe `y1` would be `height`. I'd have to see your code for more a more specific solution.

Comment: Hmmm, this is what I'm doing where I change the height of the 2nd area to larger value. Have a look at the example from the SO question I linked. I've got the same problem but with an area.

Comment: @amiawizard what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've accomplished what I need, just needed to translate the area to the bottom of the svg before the transition so it wouldn't push downward during transition.